# Create mdb table from C# and using OLE OBJECT field

Tags: c#, database, image, ole, sql-scripts

I am creating an Access Database from C# code and using text files to hold the script that is used to create them.

One of the fields I need to create is a image field from my SQL knowledge. The way it needs to get handled in the Access DB requires it to be an OLE OBJECT field.

I cannot find anything in any of my sources that describes how to do this in the SQL script. I already found al of the more basic stuff like INT, TEXT, FLOAT, BIT, etc...but I am not able to find the key word to put in the sql script for this. I have tried OLEOBJECT and OLE OBJECT as well as OBJECT and all of these failed when I tried to execute the script.

I have tried OLEOBJECT and OLE OBJECT as well as OBJECT in my script files and all of these failed when I tried to execute the script.

My expectations are to see a field with a data type of OLE Object after I execute the script.

Comment: It's been 25 years, but try LONGBINARY.

Comment: Thank you very much. That did it for me. I knew it would be something pretty simple.